# mqtt.js | client.connected returns false though client seems to be connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, iot

while playing around with mqtt.js of node.js i figured out that the value of client.connected seem to be wrong or i misunderstand something. 
I did this tutorial http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-mqtt/ and everything works fine. 
I tried to get more into mqtt, so i looked up on https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#mqttclientconnected , Description of client.connected:

> Boolean : set to true if the client is connected. false otherwise.

In order to look if it works, i modified the sourcecode for the firstline just like this

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');

  if (client.connected == true) {
        console.log("Connection successful.")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Something went wrong.")
    }

client.subscribe('presence');

console.log('Client publishing.. ');
client.publish('presence', 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());

client.end();
```

I just added the if-clause. When executing the script, I always receive the message, that something went wrong, ergo: connected --> false. 
But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `mqtt.connect()` call is asynchronous. So it returns before it has actually connected. This means as you test the `mqtt.connected` straight after calling `mqtt.connect()` it will still be false because it's not actually finished connecting yet.

You need to register event handlers to be told when the client has actually been connected.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');

client.on('connected',function(){
  client.subscribe('presence');
  console.log('Client publishing.. ');
  client.publish('presence', 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());
});

client.on('message',function(topic,message){
  console.log("received message on " + topic);
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

This code connects to a broker, subscribes to the topic `presence` then publishes a message to that same topic. When it receives a message on the `presence` topic it prints it out then exits.

Comment: The connection is async bit the function itself isn't as it returns immediately. Really seems like ```.connect``` should be awaitable and return a promise of the client.